# How do I see current average battery statistics on Android 5.1.1 & Nexus 5

Tags: battery-life

I want to see what my current, calculated standby and daily battery life statistics are before Android M is available on my device, so I can see if I've actually an improvement.

Is it possible for me to see such stats on the phone itself?

Comment: The best statistics natively can be seen from the service `batterystats`. Do "[tag:adb] `shell dumpsys batterystats`" to see the magic. [My answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/118709/96277) or [Matthew Read's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/113421/96277) should give you a hint. Otherwise, consider third-party apps to log the statistics for some interval. [GSam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm&hl=en), [BBS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats&hl=en) or BatteryStatsPlus can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method of doing this would be to install [GSam Battery Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm). It gives a clear representation of what functions are draining the battery *very* precisely and does not "package" battery consumers as the stock monitor does. (Packaging being taking separate processes and representing them as a single entity in it's consumption.

Google play services is one of the big offenders of this. Stock will usually give a 15x larger burden to GP services when in fact battery drain may just be pinned on it from the kernel or system.

Here's a nice snapshot comparison.

Stock:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Standby is not even listed as an entity on GSam, but is instead delegated to each offending process.

(Both screenshots are taken at 80% charge. Be aware that GSam just scales the used amount to 100% while the stock does not.)

GSam Battery Monitor (Google Play Store):

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Personally, the stock monitor seems to be a bit buggy and unreliable anyway. 1% for screen? Really?

Comment: I know all of the pics just became identical. I'm looking at it. (Fixed)

Comment: Please don't mess up with the revisions and  the images are not identical. See [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/editing)

Comment: @firelord, they are not identical because I fixed them. Something broke when I added the link to the play store for GSam. That and a note that GSam's measurements are based on percentages of the used battery while stock uses total battery life for its percentages. No other edits were made.

Comment: Don't know what you're saying but anyhow, unless you've something to fix in the post (grammatical) or add something new, please let it be like it is now.